# Cannot Modify Realm object while iterating through results

Tags: android, realm

Realm throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` while updating `Model` class.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: No outside changes to a Realm is allowed while iterating a RealmResults. Use iterators methods instead.
```

This is my code -

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmQuery<Model> query = realm.where(Model.class);
query.equalTo("decision", getString(android.R.string.yes));
ListIterator<Model> listIterator = query.findAll().listIterator();
realm.beginTransaction();
while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
    Model model = listIterator.next();
    model.setDecision(getString(android.R.string.no));
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a normal loop

```
realm.beginTransaction();
int size = results.size();
for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  results.get(i).setDecision(getString(android.R.string.no));
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: But the exception says `Use iterators methods instead.`

Comment: Still not working though I am not getting the error its only modifying half the items, the other half just remains the same.

Comment: @RemiJemli Traversing in reverse direction is the only solution I guess

Comment: If you got it working please edit my answer or update yours.